# Longest Suffix Racket

Tags: list, racket, complexity-theory, suffix

I have to get in racket in under O (n^2) time complexity longest suffix of two lists of different sizes.I am forbidden to use reverse on the lists or a helper prefix function and I need to get the result in the same order.

```
(define (common-suffix L1 L2)
  (if (= (length L1) (length L2))      
     (if (= 0  (min (length L1) (length L2)))
         '()         
         (if (equal? (car L1) (car L2))
             (append  (cons (car L1) null) (common-suffix (cdr L1) (cdr L2)))
             (append (common-suffix (cdr L1) (cdr L2)) null)))
     (if (< (length L1) (length L2))
         (common-suffix L1  (cdr L2))
         (common-suffix (cdr L1) L2))))
```

This is my implemantation and I only need to know if it's under O (N^2) time complexity. Thank you:)

Comment: Note: `(cons (car L1) null)` can be written `(list (car L1))`

Comment: Have you tried `(common-suffix '(a b c d y) '(a b c d x))` ? I expected the suffix to be empty.

Comment: i have to write a recursive fuction using either tail or stack , what i have wrote gets the correct longest common suffix but i dont know how to calculate it's time complexity.

Comment: The longest common suffix between `(a b c d y)` and `(a b c d x)` is `()`. Your function returns `(a b c d)`. Many other examples do work though. Do you have a test suite?

Comment: Your implementation is not below *O(n^2)* complexity. Notice both `length` and `append` are themselves *O(n)* functions in Racket, so applying them recursively for the length of the list will make the resulting complexity *O(n\*n)*.

Comment: oh yea you are right soegaard there is a mistake somewhere in my code i will review it thank you !! thank you you too asserfamaru i will try again with a tail recursive method